# FillProperty Animation WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Как в коде реализовать анимацию смены цвета для, например, `Path.Fill`.
Когда задаю `ColorAnimation`, то выдаёт эксепшен:

> Исключение типа "System.ArgumentException" возникло в
>   PresentationCore.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Параметр AnimationTimeline типа
>   "System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation" нельзя использовать
>   для анимации свойства "Fill" типа "System.Windows.Media.Brush".

```
ColorAnimation clr = new ColorAnimation();
clr.To = Color.FromRgb(30, 30, 30);
clr.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);

lic.BeginAnimation(Path.FillProperty, clr);
```

Comment: Ну, `Fill` — это `Brush`, понятно, что `Color` не подходит. Тип же не соответствует.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы задаете анимацию `Color`, а не анимацию `Fill`. Если хотите выполнить анимацию `Fill` с использованием `ColorAnimation`, то нужно указать свойство `Color`:

```
<Path Fill="Red">
    <Path.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Fill.Color">
                        <ColorAnimation To="Black" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Path.Triggers>

    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="10" RadiusY="15"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не принципиально где реализовывать анимацию - в коде или средствами WPF, то вот здесь разбирается способ через триггеры WPF:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158500/wpf-animate-background-color